# How to debug why LAN file copy speed is slow between 2 Apple machines on same LAN?

Tags: networking, ssd, file-transfer, apple

I've got two fast Apple machines on the same LAN (they are ethernet wired, plugged into the same switch, sitting next to each other).

The router is a UniFi Dream Machine Pro. Access to the outside internet is very fast.

But when copying a folder with a ton of files in it (about 500GB total), Finder copy estimates tens of days to complete, and Carbon Copy Cloner says 5 hours.

I'm using SSDs on both machines. This seems crazy slow to me (and I'm pretty sure I've done it before and it was much faster), how do I figure out what's going on?

Comment: What Ethernet link speed do they both indicate? (Normally this kind of local traffic should go straight through the switch, not even touching the router.) Are those SSDs internal, are they USB-connected, etc? Which filesystem are they using? That being said, lots of tiny files commonly causes difficulties with many filesystems, sometimes even with SSDs.

Comment: Please edit your question: What kind of Macs are they? How are they connected to the router? Also the router is a UniFi Dream Machine Pro but is there a model number? There seem to be a few of them.

Comment: How many files you have in your 500GB ? - Maybe an I/O issue on one of your SSD ? - Maybe a weak SSD ?- If the network is "fast", I guess `1Gbps` link, 500GB to copy should take about 1.15 hours (~ 75 / 80 min) **in the best case**. - When you say `Finder copy`, what do you mean exactly ? Which protocol ?